# What should I put to replace the errored "this" context?

Tags: android-recyclerview, androidx, android-context

I was creating a recyclerview for a part in the homepage activity of an app I am developing. The code below is actually from a guy in Youtube and I just followed it and it worked on the homepage java. But I decided to put it in a fragment so I created a fragment and I copied the block of codes from my homepage XML to my fragment XML. I also copied the codes from my homepage java to the fragment java. However, after doing so, the "this" on the contexts are marked red now in the fragment java even though they are fine in the homepage java. What should I put to replace the "this"?

the two blocks of code are pasted below:

```
private void setRecommendedRecycler(List<Recommended> recommendedList){
    recommendedRecycler = recommendedRecycler.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewRecommended);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recommendedRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recommendedAdapter = new RecommendedAdapter(this, recommendedList);
    recommendedRecycler.setAdapter(recommendedAdapter);
}

private void setPastOrdersRecycler(List<PastOrders> pastOrdersList){
    pastOrdersRecycler= pastOrdersRecycler.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPastOrders);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);
    pastOrdersRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    pastOrdersAdapter = new PastOrdersAdapter(this, pastOrdersList);
    pastOrdersRecycler.setAdapter(pastOrdersAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:  requireActivity() or requireContext()
By the way: you should understand about the difference between activity and fragment before continuing to build your app.

Comment: thank you so muchh for your reply.  
like this?
 RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity(), RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);

Comment: oh, thank you so much. but how about for this? 
recommendedAdapter = new RecommendedAdapter(this, recommendedList);
it's error too.

Comment: YOu can also use requireContext() or requireActivity(). Actually, 'this' is a context . So you just need put a context for it.